# Need to send computed value in stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to call stored procedure, passing parameter values while computing.

```
EXEC Procedure_Name @Parameter1-1, @Parameter2
```

I don't want to use any other variable.

Comment: You can't carry out any form of computation, calculation, function call as part of calling the SP. Nada

Comment: It is not possible without using variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using `dynamic SQL` to avoid variable for calculation. Something like below should work for you.

```
DECLARE @Script     NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @Parameter1 INT
DECLARE @Parameter2 INT

SET @Parameter1 = 10
SET @Parameter2 = 10

SET @Script = N'EXEC Procedure_Name @Param1 = ' + CAST(@Parameter1 - 1 AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ', @Param2 = @Parameter2'

PRINT @Script
EXEC (@Script)
```

But its not recommended to use dynamic SQL for such simple purpose.

Comment: Why would you recommend dynamic SQL?

Comment: If inline calculations to be performed while calling SP, dynamic SQL is either option. But its not recommended for simple calculations.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do the addition in a statement before going into the stored procedure resuing parameter 1

```
set @Parameter1= @Parameter1+1;
EXEC Procedure_Name @Parameter1, @Parameter2
```